# How would I go about reloading a view controller's table view the page curl on another view controller is closed.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, page-curl

How would I go about reloading a view controller's table view after the page curl on another view controller is closed.

I have a tableview on viewController1 with a transistion using a page curl to viewController2.

viewController1 has a tableView that needs to be reloaded after the page curl is closed.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok,

in your viewControllers1 register a notification in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];
```

and add the method:

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification*)note {
   [tableView reloadData];
}
```

in your viewController2 post the notification when you will go to viewController1 or when ever you want to reload the table:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewController1's `viewWillAppear` method, you can call the table view's `reloadData` method.

Comment: I tried     [self.tableView reloadData]; in viewWillAppear  - that works in other transitions but not when a page curl is used.

Answer (score 0):

In viewController1's

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [tableView reloadData];
}
```

tableView has to be a member.

Comment: Wouldn't that have to go in viewController2 though? so that vc1's table is reloaded after the vc2's page curl closes?

Comment: If you have access to the viewController1's tableView from viewController2, you can do it in the viewDidAppear in viewController2, this will have the same effect.

Comment: I see. thanks! so, I have to figure out how to access vc1's tableView and reload it on the didDisappear method of VC2

Comment: Sorry if i ask, but you want to achieve that your tableView reloads after the transition from controller1 to controller2 ends right?

Comment: the tableView in vc1 should reload after vc2's settings have changed. vc2 is accessed via a page curl from vc1

Comment: See my second answer, this should work, without having access to the tableView from viewController2

Answer (score 0):

```
  In first viewcontoller.h  put this in viewdidload

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handle_data) name:@"reload_data" object:nil];

-(void)handle_data
{
[yourtableview reloaddata];
}

In second viewcontroller.h
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reload_data" object:self];
```